# Android Video Streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, jmf, http-streaming

I need HTTP/RTSP Video Streaming with Android. Any Ideas ?
Is that possible to go with JMF with Android ? Any Working examples ?

Already tried with 
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

Its not working with my case. Are there any specific types of videos that Android can stream ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need JMF. Android has built in support for **HTTP/RTSP video streaming**.

Try this:

```
String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```