# Want to do video streaming using RTSP?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I want to play 3gp & mp4 video in my application using RTSP. I have a URL similar to `rtsp://www.somesite.com/4600099.mp4` and using this URL I want to stream video.

I have tried this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332773/android-video-streaming%20thread) but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android can be a biatch when it comes to video, anything pre ice cream is just frustrating to work with :)

You can give the build in samples a go as well. They are located at: `\android-sdk\samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\media` (This is for android api lvl 8, the other versions of android lies in a similar folder).

Look for: `MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java` or `VideoViewDemo.java`

Comment: 11-02 19:08:43.242: E/AndroidRuntime(597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 19:08:43.242: E/AndroidRuntime(597): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 19:08:43.242: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at com.test.TestVidioStreaming.TestVidioStreamingActivity.surfaceCreated(TestVidioStreamingActivity.java:180)
11-02 19:08:43.242: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:552)
11-02 19:08:43.242: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:350)
11-02 19:08:43.242: E/AndroidRuntime(597):  at

Comment: @Saqqib I can't really help you more than to point you to the samples, I'm sorry about that but I'm usually having problems with android mediaplayer every time I use it. Also I tend to prefer to use videoview as it gives me less problems.